# Facebook Login - Log for user login attempts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

Does Facebook Login log all user login attempts on my app (failed, accepted...) ? 
Where can I see this log?

By Facebook Login I mean the API provided by FB to allow users to "login with" in my App/Website.

I use Laravel Socialite.

Answer (score 0):

There´s the App Insights - just check out the App in the developer dashboard: https://developers.facebook.com/apps. Apart from that, you would have to log stuff on your own.

Comment: Tks, @luschn . But on which part of the dashboard? I am facing an "error: close/open browser and try again" on facebook.com site (after call API but before the callback to my app)  when some users try to login with FB on my app.  That`s a very generic error, so I am trying to find any log on FB which can clarifiy this error to me.

Comment: there is a button "show analytics" in the upper right corner, when you open your app settings. you should add ALL important information in your question, add a screenshot of that error too. your main issue is with the error, not the logging ;) - also, always add the relevant parts of your code.